# Determine the orbit of $\sqrt2/2+\sqrt2/2 i$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Consider the $4th$ roots of unity, $U_4=\{1,i,-1-i\}$ which is a group. Determine the orbit of $\sqrt2/2+\sqrt2/2 i$.

---

So far, I know that $\sqrt2/2+\sqrt2/2 i=\pi/2$ is polar. How could I connect $\pi/2$ with $U_4$. can anyone give me a hit? thanks

Comment: What does "orbit" mean here? Orbit can mean many different things.

Comment: OP just wants $g \alpha$ where $g \in U_4$ and $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g \in U_4$ and $\alpha = e^{\frac{\pi}{4} i}$

Compute $g\alpha$ for every $g \in U_4$

$1 = e^{i0}$

$-1 = e^{\pi i}$

$i = e^{\frac{\pi}{2} i}$

$-i = e^{-\frac{\pi}{2} i}$

I'll leave the computations to you.